# Where is Anduin actually?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've played Shadowlands a little bit at the end so I am not familiar with much that happened in that expansion. I am now levelling my second character in Dragonflight (after a 6 month break).

I'm at the Stormwind docks and saw Greymane and Mathias Shaw "having a conversation" about Anduin. It ended with something along the lines that Anduin is still alive, but doesn't want to interact with anyone yet.

What happened to Anduin at the end of Shadowlands? Is he still in Azeroth alive? Is he the king of Stormwind?

I tried looking for answers, but all [I found was fake news](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/wow/t/didn%E2%80%99t-play-sl-what-happened-to-anduin/1436751/4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SPOILER WARNING FOR MOST OF ANDUIN'S ARC IN SHADOWLANDS BELOW

To expand on Raven Dreamer's answer: At the start of the expansion, Anduin along with Jaina, Thrall and Baine got captured during his heroic "last stand" style moment at the waystone to Oribos and imprisoned in Torghast, and part of the early game revolves around us trying to free the Horde and Alliance leadership from the Jailer's grasp.

During cutscenes in 9.0 when Bolvar asks you to go into Torghast, it is shown that Sylvanas and Anduin have multiple conversations where Sylvanas tries to convert Anduin to the Jailer's side willingly, with Anduin continuously rebuffing her attempts while making Sylvanas doubt herself. This culminates in a scene where the Jailer uses a Remnant of Arthas' soul to reshape Shalamayne, the sword that Varian Wrynn bequeathed unto Anduin, into Kingsmourne, an even stronger sword than Frostmourne from Warcraft 3 and Wrath of the Lich King. After a final attempt from Sylvanas to get Anduin to join willingly, he ended up dominated by force.

During patch 9.1, Anduin was forced multiple times to commit atrocities against leaders of the Shadowlands, including stealing their sigils so The Jailer can take his forces to Zereth Mortis, a long-forgotten area where the Shadowlands were originally created. We learn at the end of patch 9.1 that Anduin still is able to resist the Domination Magic to some extent, because he stored a conversation with Sylvanas in his Father's compass and left it behind after helping the Jailer steal the Arbiter's sigil. At this point as well, Sylvanas was freed from the Jailer's grasp after she turned against him when it turns out he lied about his true goals.

In patch 9.2, the player characters face off against Anduin as the 8th boss encounter of the Sepulcher of the First Ones raid. During this encounter, the part of Anduin that is resisting the Jailer subtly guides his actions, leading to the players being able to help him calm his doubt and restore his willpower, so he can in turn expose the Remnant of Arthas that is in Kingsmourne, allowing us to weaken it to the point where the Jailer has to intervene and force Anduin to annihilate us. Before he's able to do so, the Remnants of Varian Wrynn and Varok Saurfang help him overcome this domination and tear Kingsmourne into the component blades, releasing the Remnant of Arthas that was dominating him and breaking the domination.

After we freed Anduin and continuing after the Jailer's final defeat, a series of in game conversations and cutscenes in Bastion, Oribos and The Maw show that Anduin is struggling greatly with the atrocities that he was forced to commit while under the domination of the Jailer. He does not consider himself "clean", even though his friends do, and he is mentally anguished about the conflicting feelings of horror and exhilaration that his actions caused within him. Above all, he's worried that he WANTED to commit those atrocities, even beyond being dominated, that the domination was revealing hidden desires inside him that he didn't know he had. This is causing Anduin to be concerned that the Light might abandon him, and that if he were to call upon again, it might not answer the call.

Because of these deeply seated worries and concerns, Anduin has decided to go on a soul searching mission after the end of Shadowlands. He has left the throne in the hands of Regent King Turalyon, and no one knows where the King is, not even his close friend Genn Greymane or Mathias Shaw, spymaster of the Alliance.

Answer (score 4):

Anduin is in places unknown, trying to recover from being Dominated by the Jailer. He briefly helped Sylvanas with her penance within The Maw, but has not been seen since.

Dragonflight takes place 3 years after the end of Shadowlands, and Anduin has yet to reappear (Though Genn keeps responding to purported sightings of the King). In the interim, the Kingdom of Stormwind is lead by Turalyon, as regent.

Answer (score 0):

Shaw and Genn both were talking about Anduin it was reported that he stopped in Rachet to buy some supplies and headed south into the Barrens, but the people following him were spotted by Anduin and he lost them somewhere in the Barrens.